# Passing input field in a frameset

Tags: javascript, html

I created a frameset that is composed of three frames. The first one takes the user's name. The second frame, contains a button called greeting. And the third frame outcome.html should outcome: Hello (user's name) upon clicking on the greetings button. I'm trying to achieve it using javascript. I tried using this solution however i couldn't get it to work. Any insight on what i'm doing wrong?

Frameset:

```
<frameset rows="34%,33%,33%">
    <frame src="name.html" name="name">
    <frame src="greeting.html" name="greeting">
    <frame src="outcome.html" name="outcome">
    </frameset>
```

Name.html :

```
<body>
    <div id="fname">
        <form>
            Client Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
        </form>
     </div>
</body>
```

Greeting.html:

```
<div id="greeting">
        <form>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Greeting</button>
        </form>
     </div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
        var name = parent.name.document.getElementById("fname").value;

        parent.outcome.document.getElementById("clientname").innerText = name;
      }
</script>
```

outcome.html:

```
<body>
Dear Mr,<span id="clientname"></span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function myFunction() 
{
        var name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        document.getElementById("clientname").innerHTML = name;
}
</script>
```